# Some combinatorial Identities in Sparse Grids

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I am studying the a paper on Sparse Grid technique for approximating functions in Korobov Spaces.
See the following paper (https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/47EA2993DB84C9D231BB96ECB26F615C/S0962492904000182a.pdf/sparse-grids.pdf)
While reading the paper, I encountered the following identities.
I am specifically curious on the derivations of first and third equalities.
If somebody can help me understanding the derivation, greatly appreciated!

[image: Combinatorial Identity in Sparse Grid]

Comment: The first equality directly comes from the definition of the binomial coefficients:
$$\binom{d-1+i}{d-1} = \frac{(d-1+i)!}{(d-1)!i!}.$$ And I think $(d-1)$ means the $(d-1)$-th derivative.

Comment: Thanks, Vezen. I think you are right! Now I see why the first equality holds.

Comment: Then for the third equality, general Leibniz Rule should be applied....