# Combinatorial Identity in Sparse Grid : degree of freedom (part 2)

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

This is the follow-up question on my previous post. ([Some combinatorial Identities in Sparse Grids](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4517644/some-combinatorial-identities-in-sparse-grids))
Following Lemma is on computing degrees of freedom of the space $V^{(1)}_{n}$, and curious on deriving the third equality.
Any hints or intuitions on the derivation is much appreciated.

[image]